# How to filter deprecated time zones with NodaTime?

Tags: c#, timezone, nodatime

I would like to return to users the list of active (non-deprecated) time zone Ids. 
Using `TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default.ZoneLocations.ToList()` I can list all Time Zones, but I didn't find how to filter out the deprecated zones. In a worst case I can build up my own list based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones, but would be happier for generated list from NodaTime.

Comment: I don't believe TZDB itself has any such concept as "deprecated". I'd be interested to know where that Wikipedia page got its "format" column from. You can tell the difference between deprecated and canonical with TZDB, but it's not clear why "Etc/Zulu" is treated as deprecated whereas "Etc/GMT0" is just treated as an alias.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I added that column, based on discussion both here and on the tz mailing list about encouraging users to pick the continent/locality form.  You are right about `Etc/GMT0` and `Etc/GMT-0` also - should probably be deprecated.  I would feel more comfortable if that information came from the tzdata itself though.  I suppose it's not precisely inline with Wikipedia's policies - being that it's "original research".  I'll take it up with the tz list.

Comment: @MattJohnson: Right. I'd definitely be happy taking it from tz :)

Comment: @Zoltan - You'd have to build it out manually until such data is authoritative.

Comment: This would be really useful. I am trying to map the tzdb zones to bcl timezones, but there are many that do not exist in the WindowsMapping.MapZones and I believe some/most of them are the ones that are "deprecated". @JonSkeet you said "you can tell the difference between deprecated and canonical with TZDB". Please could you advise how I can do that? Thanks..

Comment: @user644698: You can use `TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.CanonicalIdMap` to find the canonical ID for any given ID. If they're the same, it's canonical :)